# How can I learn to read and write Spanish in Aljamiado (Arabic) characters?

Tags: resource-request, writing-system, spanish, romance-languages, arabic

The Spanish language has a [Arabic orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aljamiado) due to hundreds of years of Moorish rule. How can I learn to read and write Spanish in these characters, assuming that I can already read and write modern Spanish reasonably well in Roman characters?

Comment: Aljamiado was not a standardised orthography.

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler Would it be more correct to say that it was a convention for transcribing Romance languages in Arabic script?

Comment: By "standardized", I meant that writing Spanish in Arabic characters was a common practice that clearly developed into some sort of reasonable consensus on "this is how you do it". I didn't mean that there was an official body or ruling. I'll edit my question slightly.

Comment: Even if there is not a 100% Official Aljamiado Version (TM) Accept No Substitutes, I'm interested in learning a common version or a version that was used in one of the major Aljamiado works.

Comment: Even you consider a convention in widespread use to be a standard (as in English), I wouldn't call Aljamiado a standardised orthography. It's not like the books I've read ever said this explicitly, but the impression I get from reading details about it is that it was ad-hoc use of Arabic letters, thanks to wording in the style of “such-and-such Arabic letter represents such-and-such sound; in some texts it represents such-and-such sound; some texts use such-and-such letter for this sound instead”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I can recommend is *Glosario de voces ibéricas y latinas usadas entre los mozárabes* by Don Francisco Javier Simonet. Although it focuses on [Mozarabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozarabic_language) rather than [Old] Spanish, it has a lot of information about the use of Arabic letters in Romance languages in Iberia.

You might find the section titled *Advertencias preliminares* (page ccxv) particularly useful, as it has a list describing how each individual Arabic letter was used.

This book is from the 19th century, so it’s in the public domain. It’s also [available online](https://archive.org/details/glosariodevoces00espagoog) :-)

Comment: Much thanks, this will do wonderfully.